# Mongo db sort on calculation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

In a request to a give node endpoint I have, I get the center of a maps location from a request.query. I want to find the first 100 responses that that are closest to this point via their radial distance. To do this, i need to use Pythagoras theorem for each point and then sort the results in ascending order. Im having trouble understanding how the aggregate pipeline works and passes variables etc...

Each house has a key location which has the keys longitude and latitude:

```
Home:{
  other keys...,
  location: {
    longitude: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    latitude: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
}
```

distance calculation for each house:

```
((location.longitude - centerLongitude)^2 + (location.latitude - centerLatitude)^2)^(1/2)
```

and this is the code I have that I know is definitely wrong:

```
const centerLongitude = 53.23212 //number that comes back from req.query
const centerLatitude = 53.23212 //number that comes back from req.query

Houses.aggregate([
    { $match: {} },
    {
      $project: {
        $longDistanceSqrd: {
          $pow: [{ $subtract: ["$location.longitude", centerLongitude] }, 2],
        },
        $latDistanceSqrd: {
          $pow: [{ $subtract: ["$location.latitude", centerLatitude] }, 2],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: {
         $sqrt: {
           $distance: {
             $sum: [$latDistanceSqrd, $longDistanceSqrd],
           },
         },
      },
    },
  ])
```

Cheers for the help in advance

Comment: Have you checked the  $geoNear  functionality : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/

Comment: perfect cheers @R2D2